# Scoped Variables and WeakReferences interact strangely - some objects don't get garbage collected

Tags: java, weak-references

I am seeing some strange behavior in a Java program, and I'm wondering if the behavior is expected, and if it's documented anywhere.

I am placing some `WeakReference` objects into a collection. (Yes, I know I should use `WeakHashMap` -- it has the same odd behavior, and that's not what this question is about.)

In some circumstances, the object referenced by the last `WeakReference` placed into the collection does not get garbage collected when I expect it to.

Below, there is a collection of unit tests that show the behavior I'm seeing. All of these tests pass as written, and there are comments where the odd behavior is seen. (Tested using Oracle JDK 1.8 and OpenJDK 11.)

In the first test, I am inserting into the collection a `WeakReference` to an object that is returned from function call:

```
List<WeakReference<Person>> refs = Lists.newArrayList();
refs.add(new WeakReference(getPerson("abc")));
```

The objects that are referenced all get garbage collected as expected.

In the second test, I have create a scoped variable to hold the function's returned object, create a `WeakReference` to it, and insert that into the collection. The variable then goes out of scope, which seems like it should remove any reference. In all but the last case, this is true: the objects they reference get garbage collected. But the last one hangs around.

```
List<WeakReference<Person>> refs = Lists.newArrayList();
{
    Person person = getPerson("abc");
    refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
}
```

In the third test, I add an additional temporary scope, and explicitly use an additional scoped variable that doesn't get added to the collection. All of the items with references in the collection get garbage collected properly.

```
List<WeakReference<Person>> refs = Lists.newArrayList();
{
    Person person = getPerson("abc");
    refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
}
...
{
    Person person = null;
}
```

And in the fourth test, since I was curious if the behavior were related to the variables all having the same name -- were they somehow being interpreted as the same variable? -- I used different names for all of the temporary variables. All of the items with references in the collection get garbage collected as expected.

```
List<WeakReference<Person>> refs = Lists.newArrayList();
{
    Person person1 = getPerson("abc");
    refs.add(new WeakReference(person1));
}
...
{
    Person person4 = null;
}
```

The only explanation I can come up with is that somehow the JRE is maintaining a reference to the last object being created, even though it goes out of scope. But I haven't seen any documentation that describes it.

---

Updated 1: a new test/workaround:

If I explicitly set the scoped variable to null before it goes out of scope, the objects get garbage collected as I would expect.

```
List<WeakReference<Person>> refs = Lists.newArrayList();
{
    Person person = getPerson("abc");
    refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
    person = null;
}
```

---

Updated 2: Another new test:

The new, extraneous object doesn't need to be of the same type. This works fine.

```
List<WeakReference<Person>> refs = Lists.newArrayList();
{
    Person person = getPerson("abc");
    refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
}
...
{
    String unused = "unused string";
}
```

---

```
import com.google.common.base.MoreObjects;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

public class WeakReferenceCollectionTest {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WeakReferenceCollectionTest.class);

    static class Person {
        private String name;

        public Person() {

        }

        public String getName() {
            return name != null ? name : "<null>";
        }

        public Person setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                              .add("name", name)
                              .toString();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            final Person person = (Person) o;
            return Objects.equals(name, person.name);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(name);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void collectionWorksAsExpected() throws InterruptedException {
        List<WeakReference<Person>> refs = Lists.newArrayList();
        refs.add(new WeakReference(getPerson("abc")));
        refs.add(new WeakReference(getPerson("bcd")));
        refs.add(new WeakReference(getPerson("cde")));

        assertEquals(refs.size(), 3);

        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        evictDeadRefs(refs);

        assertEquals(refs.size(), 0);

        refs.add(new WeakReference(getPerson("def")));
        refs.add(new WeakReference(getPerson("efg")));
        refs.add(new WeakReference(getPerson("fgh")));

        assertEquals(refs.size(), 3);

        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        evictDeadRefs(refs);

        assertEquals(refs.size(), 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void collectionWithScopesWorksDifferently() throws InterruptedException {
        List<WeakReference<Person>> refs = Lists.newArrayList();
        {
            Person person = getPerson("abc");
            refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
        }
        {
            Person person = getPerson("bcd");
            refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
        }
        {
            Person person = getPerson("cde");
            refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
        }

        assertEquals(refs.size(), 3);

        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        evictDeadRefs(refs);

        assertEquals(refs.size(), 1); // last one never goes away
        assertEquals(refs.get(0).get().getName(), "cde");

        {
            Person person = getPerson("def");
            refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
        }
        {
            Person person = getPerson("efg");
            refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
        }
        {
            Person person = getPerson("fgh");
            refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
        }

        assertEquals(refs.size(), 4); // previous last one is still in there

        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        evictDeadRefs(refs);

        assertEquals(refs.size(), 1); // last one never goes away
        assertEquals(refs.get(0).get().getName(), "fgh");
    }

    @Test
    public void collectionWithScopesAndNewVariableSetToNull() throws InterruptedException {
        List<WeakReference<Person>> refs = Lists.newArrayList();
        {
            Person person = getPerson("abc");
            refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
        }
        {
            Person person = getPerson("bcd");
            refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
        }
        {
            Person person = getPerson("cde");
            refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
        }
        {
            Person person = null;
        }

        assertEquals(refs.size(), 3);

        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        evictDeadRefs(refs);

        assertEquals(refs.size(), 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void collectionWithScopesAndDifferentVariableNames() throws InterruptedException {
        List<WeakReference<Person>> refs = Lists.newArrayList();
        {
            Person person1 = getPerson("abc");
            refs.add(new WeakReference(person1));
        }
        {
            Person person2 = getPerson("bcd");
            refs.add(new WeakReference(person2));
        }
        {
            Person person3 = getPerson("cde");
            refs.add(new WeakReference(person3));
        }
        {
            Person person4 = null;
        }

        assertEquals(refs.size(), 3);

        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        evictDeadRefs(refs);

        assertEquals(refs.size(), 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void collectionWithScopesAndExplicitlySetToNull() throws InterruptedException {
        List<WeakReference<Person>> refs = Lists.newArrayList();
        {
            Person person = getPerson("abc");
            refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
            person = null;
        }
        {
            Person person = getPerson("bcd");
            refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
            person = null;
        }
        {
            Person person = getPerson("cde");
            refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
            person = null;
        }

        assertEquals(refs.size(), 3);

        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        evictDeadRefs(refs);

        assertEquals(refs.size(), 0);
    }

    @Test
    public void createUnrelatedVariable() throws InterruptedException {
        List<WeakReference<Person>> refs = Lists.newArrayList();
        {
            Person person = getPerson("abc");
            refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
        }
        {
            Person person = getPerson("bcd");
            refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
        }
        {
            Person person = getPerson("cde");
            refs.add(new WeakReference(person));
        }
        {
            String unused = "unused string";
        }

        assertEquals(refs.size(), 3);

        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        evictDeadRefs(refs);

        assertEquals(refs.size(), 0);
    }

    private void evictDeadRefs(List<WeakReference<Person>> refs) {
        final Iterator<WeakReference<Person>> it = refs.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            final WeakReference<Person> ref = it.next();
            if (ref.get() == null) {
                logger.debug("evictDeadRefs(): removing ref");
                it.remove();
            } else {
                logger.debug("evictDeadRefs(): ref is not null: " + ref.get());
            }
        }
    }

    private Person getPerson(String s) {
        return new Person().setName(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449409/does-assigning-objects-to-null-in-java-impact-garbage-collection

Comment: Not really a duplicate to the question I'm asking. And as you can see from my code above, the accepted answer on that question contradicts what I'm seeing and the workarounds I've found.

Comment: As a side note, there is no reason for constructs like calling a 3rd party library method `Lists.newArrayList()`. It has no benefit over a straight-forward `new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. This attempt at a somewhat-minimal code sample was adapted in stages from some real code, and that's an artifact that I didn't think to factor out. It didn't occur to me to look at it in that level of detail, since it didn't have any bearing on the question I was asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are seeing some interactions with how the Java code is compiled to byte code. Two important things to note:

1. The Garbage collector does not guarantee when, or even if, an object will be collected. The guarantee is on which objects won't be.
2. Byte code does not have "local variables". Instead it has a local stack, with many stack frames. A local variable is translated into a specific location in a stack frame.

Because of #1, the scoping curly braces of Java are not required to be implemented as a new stack frame. Instead, the java compiler can create one stack frame for the whole method, and use it in a way that is consistent with the scoping rules. This means, in the second test, the local variable `person` is represented by a stack frame index that lives until the end of the method, preventing garbage collection.

Because of #2, and because local variables must be initialized before they are used, the java compiler can reuse one index of a stack frame to represent multiple local variables, so long as no two of them are ever in scope at the same time. Thus, all of your "different" `person` local variables in tests 3 and 4 end up being the same location on the stack.

TL;DR: Don't expect garbage collection to be consistent. When an object is collected can be affected both by which JVM GC you are using, and by the implementation specific details of your Java compiler.

Comment: OK, I can see that. It strikes me as counter-intuitive since I think of an out-of-scope variable being *gone*, but your explanation makes sense too. I guess this is yet another example of the Law of Leaky Abstractions.

Comment: @jwismar it’s even more counter-intuitive, as being in scope doesn’t imply preventing garbage collection per se. See [Can java finalize an object when it is still in scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24376768/2711488) and [finalize() called on strongly reachable objects in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26642153/2711488). In practice, it often depends on the optimization state of the code, i.e your example running exactly once exhibits hidden dangling references of variables out of scope, whereas executing the code multiple times in one JVM may make it experience premature collection.

Answer (score 0):

with Foo bar = new Foo();

- first, you create a reference to an object
- second, you create the Foo object itself.

So long as that reference or another exists, the specific object can't be gc'd. however, when you assign null to that reference...

bar = null ;
and assuming nothing else has a reference to the object, it's freed and available for gc the next time the garbage collector passes by.

Comment: All that is true. But then the variable goes out of scope and it seems like there shouldn't be a reference anymore.